# How to migrate from H2 DB to Postgresql in an existing JHipster application?

Tags: java, jhipster, h2, liquibase, jsonb

I have a `JHipster` Application using `Postgresql` DB in `prod` profile and `H2` DB in `dev` profile. 
My `Postgresql` schema has `JSONB` columns which I am handling in `JPA` using [vlad's JsonTypeDescriptor](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-objects-using-generic-hibernate-types/) 
The `liquibase` for `postgresql` works as expected. 
It creates tables in postgres schema with type as `jsonb`

However, the IT Test cases fail with various exceptions starting with `Could not create bean with name 'LiquibaseConfiguration'`. 
Then propagates through `unkown data type JSONB`

I understand that **H2** does not support **JSONB** column. 
What I am looking for is a way to run the **Integration test** cases generated by **Jhipster** using **Postgresql db**.

If it all this is possible, i.e., to run Test cases using a test DB config of Postgresql, what would be the `properties` that I need to change in order to run the tests using `postgres`?

I tried various combinations of changes including changing `pom.xml`, `application-dev-h2db.yml`, `WebConfigurer.java` etc but nothing seemed to work. 
Either the driver was not supported, or the `JSONB` was not supported.

I need a set of properties/ classes that I need to change in order to migrate from **H2** to **Postgresql** DB for Test Cases.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 parts in your question:

1. how to use postgresql in dev
2. how to use postgresql in unit tests

For dev, copy your `.yo-rc.json` file to an empty directory, edit it to change "devDatabaseType": property to "postgresql", generate project with `jhipster`command, compare with your own project and adapt it.

For tests, it requires more work, change properties in src/test/resources/application.yml. Additionally you may want to use TestContainers to run postgresql in docker. See https://github.com/intesys/generator-jhipster-testcontainers